# finding annual averages using pandas in python

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

my data looks like this

```
unit  year   SURQ
10001  2012   89
10002  2012   83
10003  2012   88
10001  2013   75
10002  2013   69
10003  2013   59 
10001  2014   36
10002  2014   59
10003  2014   84
```

I want to find the annual average values for SURQ by unit. For example average SURQ in 2012 for unit 10001 = ???

I tried using pivot tables

```
avgSURQ = pd.pivot_table(df,index=['year'])
```

and groupby

```
avgSURQ = SURQ.groupby('year')
```

but I think I am getting the syntax wrong so it doesn't work. I am new to python so I might be misunderstanding the examples online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> df.reset_index().groupby(['unit','year'])['SURQ'].mean()
unit   year
10001  2012    89
       2013    75
       2014    36
10002  2012    83
       2013    69
       2014    59
10003  2012    88
       2013    59
       2014    84
Name: SURQ, dtype: int64
```

Or with a pivot table:

```
>>> pd.pivot_table(df.reset_index(),columns=['unit','year'],aggfunc=np.mean)
      unit   year
SURQ  10001  2012    89
             2013    75
             2014    36
      10002  2012    83
             2013    69
             2014    59
      10003  2012    88
             2013    59
             2014    84
dtype: int64
```

Comment: can i do the same thing using a pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it using `pivot_table()`:

```
In [169]: x.pivot_table(index=[x.index,'year'], values='SURQ').reset_index()
Out[169]:
    unit  year  SURQ
0  10001  2012    89
1  10001  2013    75
2  10001  2014    36
3  10002  2012    83
4  10002  2013    69
5  10002  2014    59
6  10003  2012    88
7  10003  2013    59
8  10003  2014    84
```

PS but i think using `groupby()` will be faster and will require less memory

Data:

```
In [168]: x
Out[168]:
       year  SURQ
unit
10001  2012    89
10002  2012    83
10003  2012    88
10001  2013    75
10002  2013    69
10003  2013    59
10001  2014    36
10002  2014    59
10003  2014    84
```